# ExpressJS - Sequelize - Unrecognized Data Type

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I manually created a sql database and am now trying to set up my sequelize models to match the columns in my sql tables, but I've run into an issue with my model related to an unrecognized field type. I can't seem to pinpoint the error and if it is related to not matching the data type for a field in my database or that the sequelize does not recognize some of my code.

Here is my error:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:90
      throw new Error('Unrecognized data type for field ' + name);
            ^
Error: Unrecognized data type for field pattern
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:90:13)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/index.js:2874:23
    at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3395:24
    at /Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3073:15
    at baseForOwn (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/index.js:2046:14)
    at Function.mapValues (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3394:9)
    at new Model (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:74:50)
    at Sequelize.define (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:577:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/app/models/imagesModel.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/app/routes.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Here is my model:

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host: 'database-host',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});


var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'pattern'
    },
    color: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageUrl'
    },
    imageSource: {
        type: sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageSource'
    },
    description_id: {
        type: sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'description_id'
    }
});

module.exports = Images;
```

Comment: This [doc page](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/#your-first-model) shows the type as `Sequelize.STRING` not `sequelize.STRING`.  Note the leading capital S.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that your code should be:

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host: 'database-host',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});


var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'pattern'
    },
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageUrl'
    },
    imageSource: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageSource'
    },
    description_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'description_id'
    }
});

module.exports = Images;
```

You can refer to http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/, http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/ or an example here: https://github.com/thanhson1085/angular-admin-seed/blob/master/server/models/user.js

Comment: Don't see it that way here: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/getting-started/#your-first-model

Comment: Did you read: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/, I just change `sequelize` to `Sequelize`. It works for you?

Answer (score 2):

You use your sequelize constructor to define your table with the `sequelize.define()` method, while you use the object `Sequelize` in which your sequelize package was assigned to, to carry out functions on each of your values in your nested object. 
For example,

```
color: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'color'
}
```

and not,

```
color: {
  type: sequelize.STRING,
  field: 'color'
}
```